# How do I use a pg_search_scope with rails-autocomplete-jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete

I am using both [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) and [rails-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete)

I have a search scope, powered by `pg_search`, that is used like this: `Node.node_search(query)`.

I have tried using that method `node_search` with the `autocomplete` call on my `Node` controller, like so:

```
autocomplete :node, :node_search
```

But I get an error that there is no column on `Node` named `node_search`.

I also tried doing say `autocomplete :node, :name, scope: :node_search` but that only queries the column `node.name`. It doesn't actually pass the search query to my `Node.node_search` like I want.

Basically, what I want to happen is, whenever someone types in 1 or 2 characters, rather than checking the `name` column or any other column on my `Node` model, I want it to send that query to `Node.node_search` (which accepts queries successfully now).

How do I achieve this?

**Edit 1**

Ideally, I would love to be able to do this without having to do it in JS. If that doesn't exist, I suppose I can use JS. But I would prefer to just use something in the actual rails-jquery-autocomplete gem.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your autocomplete send requests to your node_search route :

```
$("your autocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "your endpoint url",
        data: { query: request },
        success: function (data) {
            $this.val(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('oops')
        }
    });
});
```

});'

Comment: There anyway to do this without JS? i.e. with using some method that `rails-jquery-autocomplete` has that I haven't seen or anything of the sort?

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
autocomplete :node, :node_search, scopes: [:named_scope_1, :named_scope_2, ...]
```

As it receives an array of scopes and chain them.

You must have your scopes defined in the model:

```
scope :prospects, -> ()    { where prospect: true }
```